# For $f$ periodic, $g\to 0$ the integral of $fg$ converges (under some more conditions)

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, periodic-functions

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that:

- $f$ is periodic, with finitely many zeros in a period
- The average value of $f$ on a period is $0$
- $g$ is monotonic decreasing and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$

Prove that $$\int_c^{\infty}f(x)g(x)\, dx<\infty$$ for any finite $c$, where the integral is taken in the Reimann sense (in particular, it need only be conditionally convergent).

Note: Can the "finite zeros" requirement be dispensed with or replaced by something weaker? Is it really necessary for $g$ to be continuous?

Comment: I suspect the requirement to have finitely many zeros somehow prevents you from concocting a $g$ that sits at $0$ just about everywhere $f$ is negative, while being sufficiently positive where $f$ is positive to prevent the series from converging. Somehow.

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't tell us anything at $\infty$. For instance, take $f=\sin x$ and $g=x$, when the integral no longer converges.

Also, note that the final integral is in the Reimann sense (not Lebesgue) since in general the integral is not absolutely convergent, only conditionally.

Comment: @dfeuer Interesting idea; it would be nice to see if it can be used to construct a counterexample without the finite zeros condition.

I added the finite zeros condition because it allowed for a simple heuristic proof.

Answer (score 1):

[Original version] can't be quite right, because we could take one function to be $\sin x$ and the other to be $1/x$ where $\sin x>0$ and $1/x^2$ where $\sin x<0$.

Edit: with suitable adjustments to the hypotheses, one true version I could imagine would be a continuous analogue of the generalized "alternating decreasing" convergence: given $a_n$ positive and monotone decreasing to $0$, and given $b_n$ with partial sums $b_1+\ldots b_n$ bounded, summation by parts shows $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

Comment: Aha, so continuity of $g$ is important. Thanks! Hope you don't mind if I tweak the question now to assume $g$ is continuous instead of merely integrable...

Comment: I don't mind tweaks, but/and I don't think that particular tweak is enough to help: given $f$, one could incorporate continuity-making transitions that are very short and steep, to the extent of affecting the integral as little as desired (certainly a finite amount).

Comment: You raise a good point. The nuclear option is to make $g$ monotonic decreasing, which I also wanted to stay away from, but now seems necessary.

Thanks for the insights, it would be neat developing them into counterexamples to show that the resulting conditions on $g$ are "tight".

Comment: Which raises the question again: does $g$ need to be continuous?

Answer (score 1):

This is the skeleton of the proof I had in mind.

Assume $f\not\equiv 0$. Let $\tau$ be the minimal period of $f$. Partition $\mathbb{R}\mod\tau\mathbb{Z}$ by the points $t_i$, which are the zeros of $f$ at which $f$ changes sign. Since $f$ has a finite number of zeros in a period, there are also a finite number of sign-changing zeros. Explicitly, the domain is partitioned into $$\bigcup\left([t_i,t_{i+1})+\tau\mathbb{Z}\right)$$
So $f$ alternates sign on these intervals. Form an upper bound for the integral by estimating the contribution from positive regions as $$g(t_i)\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}f(x)\,dx$$ and the contribution from negative regions as $$g(t_{i+1})\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}f(x)\,dx$$

Now that things have been approximated by step functions, we are back to the discrete case and arguments like those in paul's edit should apply.

Comment: How do you know a minimal period exists? For example, Dirichlet's function is periodic with period $1/n$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, but of course this has infinitely many zeroes en each period.

Comment: The dirichlet function is discontinuous everywhere, yet we assumed that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: For a proof that a minimal period exists, suppose for contradiction that one didn't. Let $\tau_i$ be a decreasing sequence of periods that approaches $0$ as $i\to\infty$. Pick two points $x,y$. Then we can form a sequence $x_n=x+m\tau_n$ where $m$ is an integer chosen such that $|x_n-y|<\tau_n$. By continuity, $f(x)=f(x_n)=f(y)$ so $f$ is constant, hence $f\equiv 0$, contradiction.

Comment: Perfect. I was just pointing out a proof was necessary! +1 I would suggest appending that to the answer.